# Convert pointer location and length to an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers

Sorry if this should be obvious but I'm not finding the answer.
This is part of some code I am using and I save the reference to tempData and the length. I need to know how to use that reference and the length to later retrieve the CGPoints. Is this possible? Thanks for any help!

```
- (void)setData:(float *)theData length:(int)length {

    CGPoint *tempData = (CGPoint *)calloc(sizeof(CGPoint), length);
    for(int i = 1; i < length - 1; i++) {
        tempData[i] = CGPointMake(i, theSampleData[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not fully understand your question, but if you're attempting to access those numbers from another method later on, I would either set the return type to the CGPoint, or make a global variable, like `@property CGPoint tempDataPoint` in your @interface, then set it by self.tempDataPoint = tempData; and access it by self.tempDataPoint. ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you're dynamically allocating memory and using it to store values. Sure, you can do that.

Instead of making your setData method create a local variable tempData, make tempData an instance variable of your class. Set it to nil in your init method. Also make your length variable an instance variable and initialize it to zero.

In your setData method, allocate the pointer and save your data to it. Also save the length.

Then, anywhere else in your class, you can simply index into your tempData variable, just like you are doing to set the values.

Write a dealloc method for the class that checks to see if tempData is nil. If it's not, free it.

This is basic C memory management using malloc'ed memory (or calloc'ed memory - same thing) and pointers.

Comment: Hm, not sure `tempData` would be a great name for an ivar. Also, `nil` is a little misleading -- `NULL` would be better. Good point about checking for null before calling `free` though!

Comment: Agreed about the variable names. I decided that using the names the OP used would make my point clearer, and digressing into a discussion on variable naming would be confusing. Good point on using NULL as the zero value. I've been doing objective C long enough I'm in the habit of using nil, but NULL is the C zero pointer convention, so it's a better choice.

Comment: So, this was way more simple than I was trying to make it. Thanks @bshirley as well as Duncan C for the quick responses. Duncan's idea of just 'index into it' pointed me right though. For some reason I was thinking I needed to cast or convert to an array type before looking into indexes of it since CGPoint isnt an array type. Got it working now though!

Comment: @Scott F, in C, a pointer to a scalar and an array of scalars/structs are the same thing. You just allocate a block of memory big enough to hold the number of structures you need, and then cast the pointer to the correct type. The C compiler takes care of the pointer math and it just works.

Answer (score 2):

You allocate the space, but the pointer to the new storage is local in scope and will be lost.

You want to use a property (or instance variable) to store the value.

the preferred method is to use a class extension inside your .m file to keep that information private:

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint *points;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger pointCount;
@end
```

You should also implement

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [super dealloc];
  free(points);
  points = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. A small clarification: in non-ARC code, the call to `[super dealloc]` should be at the end of the `dealloc` implementation, but if ARC is enabled, it's illegal to call `[super dealloc]`, so simply omit the call (the compiler will insert it for you). Also, note that auto-synthesis will name the ivar `_points` rather that `points`.

Comment: Also, as @DuncanC points out, it would be advisable to make sure the ivar's not null before passing it to `free`.